# How to scroll down window in laravel dusk test case

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk

In my case follwing commands are not working

```
    ->scrollTo('#required_button')->pause('6000')
    ->driver->executeScript('window.scrollTo(0, 500);')
    ->script('window.scrollTo(0, 500);')
```

I have searched more times but i can't find a solution for this problem. This problem occurs when run the laravel dusk test case click some button but that button show when scroll down the page.

Required button comes with clicking another button and then popup modal, bottom of that modal required button initiated. so i need popup window scroll down to find required button.

Comment: I usually use [scrollIntoView](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView) on the specific button e.g. `driver->executeScript('document.getElementById("required_button").scrollIntoView()')`

Comment: thank you for your attention, how can i add pause() after your code line. Beacuse adding pause() after this code line provide some errors

Comment: I got some correction by creating private function with your code and then can add some pause time thank you very much for your response

Comment: Adding `--disable-smooth-scrolling` in your base dusk test might also help.

Comment: Ok i'll check it